# Sum substring of cell if cell contains +

Tags: excel, countif

I have a participation list that I have to snazz up a bit.

```
Column
Yes
Yes
no
Yes +1
Yes +3
no
```

The sum of this has to be 8. 4 yes + 4 extra people.

I started with:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D31, "YES*")+2
```

(The number 2 are the hosts so they are static) and that works nice.
I can also add 1 if the row has a + sign in it, but I cannot add the +3 (or rather it becomes a 1.

Any help?

I need to extract the number of the row IF the row has a + and add that to the total.

Comment: It would be easiest to add another column that includes the amount of people being added and then you could merely sum that column.

Comment: Fun little question :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution, although it requires an extra column.

In a column, say `E`, you can use the following next to each cell:

```
=IFERROR(INT(RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-FIND("+",D2))),"")
```

This will get the number right of the + sign and convert it to an integer value. If there is no plus, it will return an empty string for the row.

In your total cell, you can then do:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D31, "YES*")+SUM(E2:E31)
```

To sum up the new column in addition to number of yeses.

[image]

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I get circular reference error.

Comment: @Mr.Glaurung Make sure to not put the count/sum formula in the range `D2:D31` or `E2:E31` because those are part of the calculation. Place the first formula in row 2 of the spreadsheet in the column you want the extras in, and drag down from the corner for it to auto-fill each formula with the corresponding row number in place of 2.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit messy, but depending on how simple your data set is, you could adjust the formula like this for each combination:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D31, "Yes")+2*COUNTIF(D2:D31, "Yes +1")+4*COUNTIF(D2:D31, "Yes +3")
```

Comment: It can be anything from +1 to +12 so it's not a good solution, but thanks. I actually didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

For Yes you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(MID(A1:A6,SEARCH("Yes +",A1:A6)+1,LEN(A1:A6)),0)*1)+COUNTIF(A1:A6,"Yes*")
```

For No you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(MID(A1:A6,SEARCH("No +",A1:A6)+1,LEN(A1:A6)),0)*1)+COUNTIF(A1:A6,"No*")
```

Both an array formula so enter as such through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

another way

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Yes",A2)),1,0)+IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("+",A2)+1,99),0)
```

[image]